# Brunch is not compiling a SASS file with sass-brunch

Tags: sass, brunch

I am building a project using SASS, CoffeeScript, Jade and Brunch. Everything works perfectly, except that my `application.sass` is not compiling.

Here is my brunch `config.coffee`

```
exports.config = 
    modules:
        definition: false
        wrapper: false
    conventions:
        assets: /^app\/views/
    files:
        javascripts: joinTo:
            'app.js': /^app\/scripts\/.*/
            'index.js': /^app\/scripts\/index\.coffee/
        stylesheets: joinTo:
            'app.css': /^app\/styles\/application\.sass/
```

my node `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "disynr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Website builder",
  "main": "public/index.html",
  "devDependencies": {
    "brunch": "^1.8.5",
    "coffee-script-brunch": "^1.8.2",
    "javascript-brunch": "^1.7.1",
    "sass-brunch": "^1.8.11",
    "watch": "^0.16.0"
  },
  "author": "Samadi van Koten",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jade": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

Contents of `application.sass`

```
body
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
```

and the output from `tree app`

```
app
├── scripts
│   ├── _helpers.js
│   ├── helpers.coffee
│   └── index.coffee
├── styles
│   └── application.sass
└── views
    ├── head.jade
    ├── index.html
    └── ui.jade

3 directories, 7 files
```

Output of `brunch b -d 2>&1 | grep application`:

```
Mon, 14 Sep 2015 20:32:31 GMT brunch:file-list Reading 'app/styles/application.sass'
Mon, 14 Sep 2015 20:32:31 GMT brunch:watch File 'app/styles/application.sass' received event 'add'
```

The file `public/app.css` which should be built by Brunch, does not exist after running `brunch build` or `brunch watch`.
I am using Mac OS X Yosemite. If any more information is required, please post a comment.

Comment: What is the content of `application.scss`? What is the content of `public/app.css` after you build?

Comment: @es128 I have updated the question with the information

Comment: Let's see what the brunch debug messages have to say about what's going on. Try running `brunch b -d 2>&1 | grep application`

Comment: @es128 added it to the bottom of the question

Comment: Looks like it is not even trying to compile it. Any chance the `sass-brunch` node module is not actually installed despite being listed in package.json? You could also try installing the latest version, 1.9.0, which should vastly improve performance for compiling the .sass format.

Comment: If that doesn't work, see what happens if you add a small .scss file to the project.

Comment: @es128 thanks for all your help, all I did was update the version in my package.json to 1.9 and run `npm install`. Then it worked! Thanks again

Comment: @es128 could you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sass-brunch` plugin previously required the ruby gem to process the .sass syntax. Now that support has been added to libsass, the native extension sass compiler, `sass-brunch` v1.9+ does as well.

To resolve the issue:

`npm install sass-brunch@1.9 --save`

Comment: This just solved my issue with the current brunch version